# Permamently amend Vim font size

Tags: windows, vim

Warning: first-time Vim "user"

I'd like to make the GUI font much bigger.

It is installed on a modern windows 32-bit machine.

I've used the `Edit` menu and found a good font using `Select Font...`

Then I entered the command:

`set gfn?`

To return ...

`guifont=Consolas:h16:cANSI`

Now apparently I need to add something to my `vimrc` file. I think I have found the file here?:

[image]

So why am I now struggling to make the changes?
Whichever way I try (notepad or via Vim>Open) to open this file it seems to be read-only.
I assume once open I need to add something like the following at some point(?) in the file?

```
if has('gui_running')
  set guifont=Consolas:h16:cANSI
endif
```

Comment: If you want to run something only in gvim it should go into _gvimrc.

Comment: @Cubic the only file I can find like the name you mention is `gvimrc_example.vim` - do I need to create a `_gvimrc` file? If so - how? Where should it be created saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `_vimrc` lives under `Program Files`, Windows is trying to protect you from potentially damaging the system (and is preventing potentially malicious programs from doing the same).

In order to edit your `_vimrc`, you need to be running Vim as administrator. Right-click the **gVim** icon and select **Run as administrator** from the menu. You should then be able to edit the file.

You'll probably want to make lots of other changes to this file over time; you'll have to remember always to edit it as administrator.

Comment: +1 Can my code get placed anywhere within the `_vimrc` file? Cubic mentioned just editing a `_gvimrc` file - I can only find a file called `gvimrc_example.vim`?!

Comment: @whytheq You have the choice. You can either put it in a new file called `_gvimrc` alongside your `_vimrc` (in which case it will only get run in `gvim` and not in the standard terminal `vim` you get in a command window, so you don't need the `if` around it), or add it to the `_vimrc`. You can copy and rename the example file you found as a starting point. Personally, I put everything in my `_vimrc`; that way I've only got one file to manage.

Comment: thanks Matthew - 2 days in and I wondering what I'll be able to do with Vim? Can I build/compile/test/error trap all sorts of programs with this tool?

Comment: You can do pretty much anything with Vim (well, anything you'd want from an editor), if you're willing to accept the steep learning curve :-) http://vimcasts.org/episodes/archive is a good place to start.

Comment: Even before that, make sure you run `vimtutor.bat` to pick up the basics.

Comment: I'll try to find the tutor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the windows platform, but it seems that you were editing the system vimrc. try to start (g)vim, and type `:e $MYVIMRC` this should be user-lvl. usually under `$HOME`

write the setting you want there, and save.

or you could in vim, `:echo $HOME`, to see which dir is your HOME. then create the `_vimrc` file there.

Comment: using `:e $MYVIMRC` takes me to the file but when I try to edit it errors with `E303: Unable to open swap file for "C:.....\_vimrc", recovery impossible`

Comment: @whytheq, you get that error because the file you are trying to edit is in a protected directory which is blocking Vim's attempt to create a swapfile. The correct location of your `_gvimrc`, `_vimrc` and `vimfiles` is in what Vim considers your `$HOME`. In Vim, issue kent's command, `:echo $HOME` to know where to put those files and directories and create them as needed. On Win 7, this would be `C:\Users\username\_vimrc` and so on… You should never touch the system-level `_vimrc` and friends. **Never.**

Comment: @romainl `:h vimrc` says the recommended place for personal initialization on MS-DOS or Win32 is `$HOME/_vimrc` **or `$VIM/_vimrc`** (emphasis mine).

Comment: And later it says that `$HOME` is checked first. The point, here, is not to do whatever is possible but to do what is right: keep system-wide stuff in `$VIM`, out of the users reach, and keep user-specific stuff in `$HOME`. What's going to happen to the OP's `$VIM/_vimrc` when he upgrades Vim? I don't want to know and I believe he doesn't want to know either.

Comment: ok thanks fellas  - if I run `:echo $HOME` then it returns `M:\`. So I will try putting the system-level files back to the way they were. Then I will save a copy of the `_gvimrc` example file to `M:\` and see what happens.