# Editing _vimrc in Windows

Tags: vim, vi, working-directory

I am having some trouble with VIM on windows, and I was wondering if anyone could be of assistance.  As of right now, I am trying to make it so that when VIM starts, it changes it's working directory to one besides the default `(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Vim 7.3)`. The way I am going about this is adding in `cd $HOME\Desktop\VimFiles`, where `$HOME` is `C:\Users\Alphabet` (Alphabet is the name of my account).

The issue I am running into right now is that after opening up `_vimrc` and adding in the line stated above, I cannot save the file, even when forcing it (with w!). I was wondering why this is and how I can go about fixing this. As an added note, I am running this in GVIM.

**Note: I have attempted to do the same thing in VIM, and am able to edit the _vimrc file fine, but when I go to it's location and open it with GVIM or Notepad++, the "cd" line doesn't show up.  Is there a reason for this?**

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What's the hint message showed in command bar after you type :w!<Enter>?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368988

Comment: I looked at the stackoverflow page listed above, and running it as an Administrator seems to have done the trick.  Thanks.  :D  Although, is there any way to make it such that I don't need to do that?  Changing file permissions or just moving Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write a file in a protected directory without the proper privileges.

In Vim, `:echo $HOME` tells you where you are supposed to put *your* `_vimrc`. In your case, your `_vimrc` should be `C:\Users\Alphabet\_vimrc` and you should put your plugins and whatnot in `C:\Users\Alphabet\vimfile\`.

**Never touch system files!**

Comment: I guess I"m a little confused because it's in the VIM folder, and I am on an administrator account.  Also, why would we put nothing in the $VIM location?  That seems to be the default location that my _vimrc is located.  So are you suggesting I just move the entire VIM program to my desktop as the download location?

Comment: 1. When you'll upgrade Vim, most of what is in `$VIM` will be overwritten. 2. What's in `$VIM` is necessary for Vim to work reliably, messing with it puts the program in an unstable state. 3. Due to loading order, placing plugins and settings in `$VIM` is at best unpredictable. That's why you must do all your customization in your `$HOME` directory and **never** touch `$VIM`, whether you are admin or not. Put your settings in `C:\Users\Alphabet\_vimrc` and your plugins in `C:\Users\Alphabet\vimfile\`, that's all there is to it.