# vim - _vimrc file on Windows 8 not working

Tags: vim, home-directory

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/86246/where-should-the-vimrc-file-be-located-on-windows-7) question but it didn't help. The solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495326/editing-vimrc-in-windows) is what I tried but it didn't work.

I am trying to create an _vimrc file on my Windows 8 computer so that the syntax of my code in vim is 1) highlighted by default and 2) maintains indents.

I entered

```
echo %UserProfile%
```

into the command prompt and it gave me C:\Users\Username.

I used vim to create a _vimrc file in C:\Users\Username and added

```
set autoindent

syntax on
```

to it. However, these changes do not register in vim.

Most questions I could find online are for Unix where the home directory is ~. The questions that did apply to Windows said to create the file in the C:\Users\Username directory which is what I'm doing.

I tried closing and reopening my command prompt but it didn't help.

Sorry if this is a really simple question; I don't use user variables that often.

Comment: Check the output of `:version` inside of vim (or `vim --version` outside.) One of the lines tells you where the vimrc should go. (For some reason some one told me it was `virc` instead of the normal `vimrc`)

Comment: It said `user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"` so I changed the name of the file from _vimrc to .vimrc. Vim still doesn't register the changes.

Comment: Can you check the output of `:scriptnames`? Does the file show up there?

Comment: Yes! I found the path to the file in /usr/share/vim/vimrc. Make your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` in the output of `:scriptnames` indicates that you are using a version of Vim provided by some unix-like compatibility layer like cygwin instead of a regular Windows build.

From the user's perspective, the cygwin environment is completely segregated from the Windows environment and you are expected to use/customize it like you would on an actual unix-like system. Mixing Windows and "Linux" (huge quotes, here) concerns is not a very good idea in such a context.

In Vim, `:echo $HOME` should tell you what your `$HOME` is from Vim's POV.

If you are indeed using cygwin, cygwin's `$HOME` is usually located here from Windows' POV:

```
C\cygwin\home\username
```

while Windows' `$HOME` is usually located here from cygwin's POV:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/username
```

In short…

- if your Vim is a regular Windows program, the standard location for your config is:

  ```
  C\Users\username\_vimrc
  C\Users\username\vimfiles\
  ```

  You can use both the console and the explorer to deal with those files and directories.
- if your Vim is provided by cygwin, the standard location for your config is:

  ```
  /home/username/.vimrc
  /home/username/.vim/
  ```

  You are pretty much forced to use the "Cygwin Terminal" to deal with those files and directories unless you get how those are mapped to Windows paths.

  *Avoid thinking in Windows terms.*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem on Windows 7 and 10. VIM's installer created a default vimrc file in the installation directory (in my case `c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`).

After deleting this file, VIM looks in my home directory.